# Aplicar Datatables a 2 Tablas, una se llenó con Ajax y la otra con PHP ambas están en la misma página

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, datatables

Buenas tardes tengo un problema con la aplicación de DataTables a dos tablas que se encuentran en la misma página, una tabla de ellas se encuentra en una modal, se aplica correctamente el diseño de DataTables en las tablas, pero en la tabla de la modal muestra como si no tuviera registros. Le quite el filtro de DataTables, pero igual si filtraba en la tabla de la modal no hacía nada y en la tabla principal si filtraba. Espero que me puedan apoyar.

> Tabla 1

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<table class="table table-hover" id="tabla_ventas">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Cliente</th>
            <th>Fecha Captura</th>
            <th>Tipo</th>
            <th>Usuario</th>
            <th>Estatus</th>
            <th>Total</th>
            <th>Movimientos</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php if($arr_ventas != NULL) : 
            $contador = 1;?>  
            <?php foreach($arr_ventas as $registro) : ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $contador;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $registro['nombre']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $registro['fechaCaptura']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $registro['tipo']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $registro['usuario']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $registro['status']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $registro['total']?></td>
                    <td>
                        <a type="button" class="btn btn-info" href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_ver" onclick="ver_productos_venta(<?php echo $registro['ideVenta'];?>);">
                            <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a type="button" class="btn btn-warning" href="<?=base_url()?>Ventas_controller/edit_venta/<?=$registro['ideVenta']?>">
                            <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="delete_venta(<?php echo $registro['ideVenta'];?>);">
                            <i class="fa fa-times" style="color:#fff;"></i>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php $contador++; 
                endforeach; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Aquí si me aplica bien el DataTables y me muestra la cantidad de registros.

> Tabla 2 (modal)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Aplico DataTables a través del nombre del estilo de la clase

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('table.table').DataTable();
    } );
} );
```

> Lleno tabla de la modal

```js
function ver_productos_venta(id_venta) {

    $("#tabla_productos_venta").find("tbody").detach();//borro tabla
    $('#tabla_productos_venta').append($('<tbody>')); //creo la tabla 

    $('#modal_ver').modal({
       backdrop: 'static',
       keyboard: false
     });

    $.ajax({
        url : "<?php echo base_url('Ventas_controller/ver_productos_venta')?>/"+id_venta,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data) {

                    var filas = data.length;
                    var contador = 1;
                    for (  i = 0 ; i < filas; i++){ //cuenta la cantidad de registros
                        var nuevafila= "<tr><td>" +
                        contador + "</td><td>" +
                        data[i].descripcion + "</td><td>" +
                        "$ "+data[i].precioCompra + "</td><td>" +
                        data[i].cantidad + "</td><td>" +
                        "$ "+data[i].preciototal + "</td><td>" ;

                        $("#tabla_productos_venta").append(nuevafila);
                        contador++;
                    }

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            swal({
              title: "Error!",
              text: "No se trajo la información de las ventas!",
              icon: "error",
              button: true,
              dangerMode: false,
            })
            .then((willDelete) => {
              if (willDelete) {
                // $('#modalEdit').modal('show');
              }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Aquí el diseño de DataTables se aplica bien pero no me guestra la cantidad de registros y como les comentaba, antes tenía filtro y export pdf pero lo quite porque quiero que primero quede estoy, igual cuando antes tenía el filtro, no filtraba y cuando exportaba el pdf aparecía vacía la tabla y es por eso que en este momento no me salen las cantidades de registros en databales.

Comment: Porque no usas la opcion ajax de datatables: https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax

Comment: Y como se aplicaría en mis tablas?

Comment: Necesitas devolver un arreglo que datatables acepte.  Aqui hay otro ejemplo: https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax